# Is there a clever way of keeping the JavaFX TreeView up to date with an underlying DOM and JPA model?

Tags: java, jpa, javafx, synchronization, treeview

Hi i am having problems keeping my TreeView up to date with an DOM like data model which is persisted using JPA.

My code is rather verbose, so i have broken it down to a sort of pseudo code for a better understanding.

my basic DOM object looks like this Node class:

```java
@Entity
public class Node{

    @Id
    private UUID uuid= UUID.randomUUID();

    @ManyToOne
    private Node parent;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="parentNode", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

    //--- some other irrelevant fields
    //--- some other irrelevant methods

    public Node getParent (){
        return this.parent;
    }

    public boolean addChild(Node child){
        boolean result = false;
        if (!isCircularReference(child)) { // this checks whether the passed child is not a distant farther etc.
            result = this.children.add(child);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Of course the Node class contains a little more, but i don't think that is relevant for the topic.

I then have a View Controller which controlls a JAVAFX TreeView object. Simplified it looks like this:

```java
public class ViewController {

    @FXML private TreeView<Node> tree;

    private Node rootNode;

    ViewController (Node root){

            Objects.requireNonNull(root);
            this.rootNode = root;
            setupView();
    }

    //some other Nodes etc.

    private void setupView(){

        TreeItem<Node> treeRootNode = new TreeItem<>(rootNode)
        this.tree.setRoot(treeRootNode);
        fillTreeNodeWithProductNode(treeRootNode , rootNode);
    }

    //recursively populates the TreeView for each child under the Node
    private void fillTreeNodeWithProductNode(final TreeItem<Node> treeNode,final Node node){
        node.getChildren().forEach(child-> {
            final TreeItem<Node> childTreeNode = new TreeNode<>(child);
            treeNode.getChildren().add(childTreeNode);
            fillTreeNodeWithProductNode(childTreeNode, child);
        });
    }

    //--- some methods for adding and Removing TreeItems under TreeItems. 
    @FXML
    private void onSaveButtonPressed(){
        // .... simplified
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

        Node oldRootNode = rootNode;
        rootNode = em.merge(rootNode);

        compareAndRefreshTreeView(rootNode, oldRootNode);
    }
}
```

This ViewController also handles the deletion and addition of Node elements to the tree.
Not shown here to keep it simple. BUT: This works fine. And as far as I can tell, it causes no problems.

The tricky bit is when using JPA to persits and manage my Node objects.
if say i use the `EntityManager.merge(E entity)` method on my **rootNode** then it will return a new instance of this *rootNode*.
This is what is causing me problems.
The *TreeView tree.getRoot* still reference the old instance used on view creation.
Meaning that i have to recreate the whole tree again using the new instance returned by the `EntityManager.merge(E entity)`  method.
This recreation results in the treeview looking different from when the user pressed the save button. (the tree is collapsed, the scoll bar position is top, etc. )
For a better User Expierence I create a reference to the TreeItem containing the rootNode prior to the merge, then after recreating the TreeView i compare both structures and expand the new TreeView when needed. As sipmly demonstrated in `ViewController.onSaveButtonPressed()`  A reference to the scollBar position is also stored.
Tis works fine but it just doesn't feel right!

So my question is: **Surely there is a more efficient way of keeping all data synchroniszed?**

I hope this code is sufficient to understanding my problem, if not, let me know.

Comment: [mcve] please (you can hard-code the backend updates/refreshes)

Comment: @kleopatra I understand your request, however It would take a while to get a working project ready with JPA etc.

Comment: repeating: mock the database part, it's not important anyway (instead of really committing/merging have a function that returns a hard-code tree of items that's different from the old) - the part you seem to have problems with (at least as I understand your question) is the keeping of tree state (like selection/expansion)